# How to show multiple form pages in single windows form application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have got a requirement to design a windows forms application using Visual Studio 2010.

According to the design I have to develop the application which contains a menu bar. On selecting of the menus from the Menu bar relevant forms should open. Now as per my requirement these menu forms should be displayed in the same parent Windows Form. Means everything should be in the single form Application.Nothing should be out of that.

The problem that I'm facing is that I don't know how to proceed with this. This is the first time I'm working on Windows Form Application leaving Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for developing an MDI application. MSDN article to guide you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could build a grid area on your form using a combination of split containers (horizontal and vertical).

Then in separate panels design each of your menu forms, with each panel visibility set to false.
When choosing a menu you would need to assign a parent (split container panel) to the menu form and set it to visible.

Comment: Do i need to add MenuBar Menu click event on each form in every panel to show the relevant Forms?

Comment: I am not exactly sure of what you want to do. If By clicking on a menu item you want to display a specific form you only need one click event (on the menu item). In the event method you'll need to set your form IsVisible property.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Create a form and give the name it to "mdiMain" and set the property [IsMdiContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.ismdicontainer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to true.
Add a MenuStrip control from the ToolBar and add some menues.

**Step 2**

Create another form and give the name it to "frmChild"

**Step 3**

Write some code in menu click event to display frmChild form in MDI Parent.

```
Dim frm As New frmChild()
frm.MdiParent = Me
frm.Show()
```

Now your application is ready. You can place your code and control in frmChild window form.

Answer (score 0):

As an option in some cases you can use WebBrowser control and manipulate html code inside depending on the menu bar selection.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx